# Making a variable available between containers?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

When I read the Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment), I get the impression that it is possible make a variable from one container available in another container when using Docker Compose.

So in container A I do in a script

```
export PASS=abc
```

and in the `docker-compose.yml`

```
containera:
  image: ...
  environment:
    - PASS

containerb:
  build: ...
  links:
    - containera:ca
```

But when I do `env` in container B, then `PASS` is empty.

**Question**

How do I make the generated value of `PASS` in container A available in container B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker only shares environment variables originating from Docker. [see their docs here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables)

Since your value is generated by a process running in `containera`, Docker has no awareness of its value.

You would either need to:

- set a static value in Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml
- set a static ENV variable with a port/endpoint for accessing a service inside `containera` that would return the generated password/token.

Comment: Doesn't bullet point 2 conflict with the second sentence? From what I understand now, then  I can't change the ENV variable that Docker gives other containers?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes I clarified the 2nd bullet, hopefully that makes more sense.